# Can you download OpenCV with Python 3.5.2?

Tags: python, opencv, python-3.5

Can you download OpenCV with Python 3.5.2? I want to set up OpenCV. But I don't know if I need 2.7 or can I use my already downloaded Python 3.5.2 version. Will it be compatible? I want learn computer vision so I can make some projects. Like a automated waste sorter. But I need to download OpenCV first. Just need some guidance. It's not like it's a straight download but a process. So if anyone can tell be if my version (on windows 10) Python 3.5.2 will work with the current OpenCV that would be great. Thanks

Comment: I'd say you can download it with any version, but aren't you more interested in **using** it with Python 3.5.2?  I suggest to edit your question (including it's title) to reflect that.

Answer (score 2):

yes, OpenCV 3 works with Python 2.7, 3.4, 3.5, 3.6 and 3.7

Comment: This answer would be better if you added some references for that information. Also, does this hold true for all the releases in the 3.x branch (even those predating some of those Python releases?)

Answer (score 0):

I think the python 3.7 still not supported, I'm having the problem too I think I need to downgrade to a stable version.

Reference: https://github.com/skvark/opencv-python/issues/106

Answer (score 0):

Well at first you need to decide what you really want to do. I guess you just do not want to learn computer vision. Even if after few days you may want to use some machine learning tools like sickit learn. In my openion just follow the following steps which may save a bunch of time. Here is the necessary steps:

1. Delete all the python version you have from control panel.
2. Download anaconda from this link:https://www.anaconda.com/download/
3. Install anaconda. When it will ask about whether you want to add anaconda in your path or not. Just give the confirmation that you want to add anaconda to your path. Although it will say it is not a wise way to install. But you should install it.
4. After successful installation you can see anaconda navigator in your start menu.
5. if you click it. Then you will find the following option:

[image: Anaconda Navigator]

5. Click the environment. you will see the following environment:[image: update description here]
6. You can see I just search for opencv and it shows what packages anaconda have now. So, the same way you can install all necessary packages based on your code and requirements.
7. To run python script, you can use spyder as an IDE or you can use jupyter note book.
   Last but most important thing, anaconda comes with python. So, you do not need to install python separately.

There is many more way you can install python and opencv. But if you are not so familiar with command platform, I guess that's the way you can save your time.